# How do I print all values in a nested dictionary in one group, not line-by-line?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to create a function that allows the user to view my full dictionary. I want to be able to output each nested dictionary together in a neat formation Like this:[image], instead of printing it out line by line [image: like this] and [image: this].

The dictioanry looks something like this:

```
#Dictionary for all the monster cards with a set of stats
monster_cards = {"Corpsemask":
                 {"Strength": 7,
                  "Speed": 1,
                  "Stealth": 25,
                  "Cunning": 15},
                 "Dustfigure":
                 {"Strength": 1,
                  "Speed": 6,
                  "Stealth": 21,
                  "Cunning": 19},
                 "Bonemonster":
                 {"Strength": 5,
                  "Speed": 15,
                  "Stealth": 18,
                  "Cunning": 22},
                 "Bonefoot":
                 {"Strength": 15,
                  "Speed": 20,
                  "Stealth": 23,
                  "Cunning": 6}}
```

I am a beginner with programming, and am doing a practice assessment, so I have a certain character count per line which is why the code may look weird. I also have to use the easygui module.
Any advice for this issue?

```
def view_catalogue():
    if len(monster_cards) > 0:
        for card, card_stats in monster_cards.items():
            msg = easygui.msgbox("Monster: " + card)

            for key in card_stats:
                msg = easygui.msgbox(key + ": " + str(card_stats[key]))
            
                
    else:
        msg = easygui.msgbox("You have no monsters in your catalogue")
```

Here is my current function:

Comment: Build a string first, then display it in a message box all at once at the very end; instead you're currently displaying one line per message box as you go along. Define an empty string and then start appending to it with `+=`. To put in a newline use `\n` in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
for key in card_stats:
    msg = easygui.msgbox(key + ": " + str(card_stats[key]))
```

Each time through this loop, you're making a brand-new message box with just one stat line.

As @RandomDavis commented above, you probably want to do it like this:

```
msg = ""
for key in card_stats:
    stat_line = key + ": " + str(card_stats[key]) + "\n"
    msg += stat_line
easygui.msgbox(msg)
```